# Efcore: The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked. Many-to-many

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

I get this exception when I save my DbContext.

[image]

the object (Vessel) I'm trying to save has a collection of other objects (System). And System has a collection of Vessels. Many to Many.

```
 public class Vessel
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<System> Systems { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class System
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Vessel> Vessels { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration of the relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vessel>()
.Property(x=>x.Id)
.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

modelBuilder.Entity<Vessel>()
.HasMany(x=>x.Systems)
.WithMany(x => x.Vessels);

modelBuilder.Entity<System>()
.Property(x => x.Id)
.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

I didn't add the HasMany() with System, because the generated SQL was sufficient

[image]

I load up all my vessels and include all what's needed.

```
Vessels = await DbContext
                .Vessels
                .Include(x=>x.Systems)
                .Include(x=>x.ExcludedTags)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation)
                .ToListAsync();
```

When the user selects a Vessel, a component is loaded (and passed the same dbcontext) where he sees more details of the Vessel.
He can then open a dialog to add Systems to that Vessel.
I load the available Systems as non-tracking

```
var systems = await DbContext.Systems.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();
```

When the dialog closes, the added Systems are added to the System list on the Vessel.

```
var selectedSystems = modalResult.Data as List<Data.System>;
if (selectedSystems is object)
{
    foreach(var system in selectedSystems)
        Vessel.Systems.Add(system);

    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But when I save. I get the error.

I don't know why it is complaining about the System object, since I only add it to the Vessel and only the reference needs to be saved.

I tried the following snippet:

`DbContext.Entry(Vessel).CurrentValues.SetValues(Vessel);`

But then I get the exception immediately, and not during save.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please include your code as code snippets instead of screenshots

Comment: Replaced the screenshots with code snippets

Comment: Most probably you are invoking the entity from a different member also or different layer like data access. You should use the same context for the same entities.

Answer (score 0):

The Include Systems line in this query:

```
Vessels = await DbContext
            .Vessels
            .Include(x=>x.Systems)
            .Include(x=>x.ExcludedTags)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation)
            .ToListAsync();
```

This is going to pull in any Systems that are linked to any Vessels that you queried.

Then you run this:

```
var systems = await DbContext.Systems.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();
```

That query is saying "Hey EF Core, give me these Systems but forget we ever talked about them."

When you attach one of those to a Vessel, you're telling EF Core you actually DO care about that one System. Then the save happens and it's holding two different instances of a System object with the same ID and it doesn't know which one you actually wanted to keep, and which instance you didn't. It also is likely confused because one of those instances will have an extra Vessel in it's collection.

So we need a way to make sure there's not two copies in there. Either lose the first one that's included, or perhaps if you load these without the AsNoTracking EFCore should know already about the ones it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by getting the the tracked System object and inserting it to Vessel object.

```
var trackedSystem = DbContext.Systems.Find(system):
Vessel.Systems.Add(trackedSystem);
```

I still find it weird that it complained it was already tracked, instead of just replacing the non-tracked with the tracked while saving. The System object did not change.